# Login Failure on MySQL database with connection string from asp.NET

Tags: php, mysql, asp.net, connection-string

I'm trying to access a database that I created through phpMyAdmin. All I want to do is display one of the tables though a gridview. However when I try to create a connection string through my web.config file I get this error:

```
[ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.]
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue) +5360365
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey) +124
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules) +95
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString) +59
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous) +24
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions) +167
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key) +61
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value) +66
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource.CreateConnection(String connectionString) +34
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +113
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +21
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +138
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +30
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +4
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +105
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls() +75
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +83
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +974
```

I don't have access to the error log, although I have contacted the database administrators and am waiting on a response from them to see if I can get access.

My connection string is:

```
<connectionStrings>    
  <add name="TheRegistrationConnectionString"         
connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;Database=faltesek__dahcookiejar;Uid=falte_aaron;Pwd=xxxxx;"
  providerName="System.Data.MySqlClient"
     />
```

The database server info is:

Server version: 5.1.73-community - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

I've tried looking around to make sure my connection string is formatted correctly. I tried a dozen different formats and can't seem to get anything to work. Until I get access to the server error logs, I thought maybe someone could see an obvious problem with what I'm doing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you add the appropriate MySQL .NET Connector libraries to project reference?
 http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net

Comment: No, I have not. What would that allow me to do?? Sorry, I'm new to this.

Comment: It's a driver for connect mysql, it's similar ado.net but for mysql, can you read  link?